# Why do I get this error when passing ViewModel to View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, view, viewmodel

When passing ViewModel to View I get the error

> The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[TraficAlert.Models.TaBarHeader]',
> but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[TraficAlert.Models.ViewModels.HeaderTelegramaViewModel]'.

I have tried to use `@model IEnumerable<TraficAlert.Models.ViewModels.HeaderTelegramaViewModel>` in the `Index.cshtml` and it works, but I need to access a property from `HeaderTelegramaViewModel`.

**Index.cshtml**:

```
@model IEnumerable<TraficAlert.Models.ViewModels.HeaderTelegramaViewModel>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaBarHeader.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaBarHeader.ParentId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaBarHeader.TStamp)
            </th>
   (...)
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaBarHeader.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaBarHeader.ParentId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaBarHeader.TStamp)
                </td>
   (...)
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.TaBarHeader.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.TaBarHeader.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.TaBarHeader.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**HeaderTelegramaController**:

```
(...)
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var applicationDbContext = _unitofwork.BarHeader.GetAllBarH().ToList();
        return View(applicationDbContext);
    }
```

**TaBarHeaderRepository**:

```
public IEnumerable<TaBarHeader> GetAllBarH()
{
    return _db.TaBarHeaders
        .Include(t => t.CategoriaFk)
        .Include(t => t.CauzaFk)
        .Include(t => t.ClasaFk)
        .Include(t => t.LucrareFk)
        .Include(t => t.RegionalaFk)
        .Include(t => t.UserFk);
}
```

**HeaderTelegramaViewModel**:

```
public TaBarHeader TaBarHeader { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categoria { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<ViewOtf> ViewOTFCollection { get; set; }
(...)
```

Why do I get the above mentioned error?

Thank you.

Comment: As the error message says it anticipates a collection of `HeaderTelegramaViewModel` but you have passed a collection of `TaBarHeader` . Either you have to map your  collection of `TaBarHeader` to a collection of `HeaderTelegramaViewModel` OR change the View's `@model`

Comment: I have created `public IEnumerable<TaBarHeader> TaBarHeaders { get; set; }` in `HeaderTelegramaViewModel` and also changed `@model` without IEnumerable but doesn't work.

Comment: The `GetAllBarH` returns *TypeA* and your view expects *TypeB*. Based on the provided code there is no implicit conversion between the two. So, the problem is not related to `List` or `IEnumerable` rather their parameterized type.

Comment: Now I got it. But, I'm a bit confused of how should I use `HeaderTelegramaViewModel` in the method `GetAllBarH()` and what are the good practices of doing this.

Comment: You should not use `HeaderTelegramaViewModel` inside your `GetAllBarH`. The mapping should be done inside the Controller's Action. You can do it manually or you can use 3rd party libraries like [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the model below in the cshtml.

```
@model TraficAlert.Models.ViewModels.HeaderTelegramaViewModel
```

And in the Index() create an instance of HeaderTelegramaViewModel:

```
var _HeaderTelegramaViewModel = new HeaderTelegramaViewModel();
_HeaderTelegramaViewModel.TaBarHeader = TaBarHeader;
```

And the class HeaderTelegramaViewModel must have:

```
public IEnumerable<TaBarHeader> TaBarHeader { get; set; } 
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categoria { get; set; } 
public IEnumerable<ViewOtf> ViewOTFCollection { get; set; }
```

Comment: If I use @model TraficAlert.Models.ViewModels.HeaderTelegramaViewModel I get this error > foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'HeaderTelegramaViewModel' because 'HeaderTelegramaViewModel' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Use instead this in the cshtml for access the list of elements:
@foreach (var item in Model.TaBarHeader)

Comment: I changed it and I got the original error > The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary...

Comment: I think it might have to do something with the method `IEnumerable<TaBarHeader> GetAllBarH()`.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the issue and your answer was the closest. I have used `@model HeaderTelegramaViewModel` in Index.cshtml; declared property `IEnumerable<TaBarHeader> taBarHeader { get; set; }` in HeaderTelegramaViewModel; changed in HeaderTelegramaController: `HeaderTelegramaViewModel headerTelegramaViewModel = new HeaderTelegramaViewModel(); headerTelegramaViewModel.taBarHeader = _unitofwork.BarHeader.GetAllBarH().ToList();`; and changed the for in the Index.cstml: `@foreach (var item in Model.taBarHeader)`.

Answer (score 0):

use :: @model TraficAlert.Models.ViewModels.HeaderTelegramaViewModel

instead of ::@model IEnumerable<TraficAlert.Models.ViewModels.HeaderTelegramaViewModel>

at the top of index.cshtml page

Answer (score 0):

See the type of your model IEnumerable<TraficAlert.Models.ViewModels.HeaderTelegramaViewModel> and apply this:

```
   public IActionResult Index()
   {
       var applicationDbContext = _unitofwork.BarHeader.GetAllBarH();
       return View(applicationDbContext);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible error I assume may come from your table head
try specifying an index considering your model is an `IEnumerable`.

So change

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaBarHeader.Id)
```

to something like this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item[0].TaBarHeader.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message explains the problem fairly clearly: you're passing in a different type than the view is expecting.

Specifically, you call `GetAllBarH()` to get the data for the view, and it returns `IEnumerable<TaBarHeader>`. Therefore the `model` declaration for the page should be:

```
@model IEnumerable<TraficAlert.Models.TaBarHeader>
```

If you really wanted `HeaderTelegramaViewModel` then you're going to have to convert the `IEnumerable<TaBarHeader>` somehow. I assume you missed that step in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I get the above mentioned error?

Because the data type **returned** in your **action** **is not the same as** the data type required on the view.

You can modify your **HeaderTelegramaController** like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   var applicationDbContext = _unitofwork.BarHeader.GetAllBarH().Select(m => new HeaderTelegramaViewModel { TaBarHeader = m }).ToList();
   return View(applicationDbContext);
}
```